# How does Clipboard work in wx?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have following function in python -

```
def GetClipboardText():
    text_obj = wx.TextDataObject()
    rtext = ""
    if wx.TheClipboard.IsOpened() or wx.TheClipboard.Open():
        if wx.TheClipboard.GetData(text_obj):
            rtext = text_obj.GetText()
        wx.TheClipboard.Close()    
    return rtext
```

It works well when I invoke this function from a UI callback handler such as button click (The UI is in wxPython). But if I invoke function directly in a script, the `wx.TextDataObject()` returns `None` and the function fails.

Questions -

1. What particular UI class is the dependency for the clipboard to work? Do I need to show a frame on screen? Is there a work around like creating an invisible frame? Is frame what the clipboard depends on or is it something else?
2. Is it possible to use clipboard in a command line app without GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing `wx.App` in your script. Many wx classes require it.